# "Add" Icon for iOS Button

Tags: iphone, web-applications, mobile, mobile-safari

I'm developing a WebApp for iOS, and I need a "add" icon for my button. Something like this:

http://www.winsupersite.com/content/content/127266/reviews/mobileme_iphone_rtm_16.jpg

The button I already have, what I need is just the "add" icon like that.

Comment: No idea why this was downrated.

Comment: This isn't Mechanical Turk - Questions get answered here - SO folks are not not going to find an icon that you could pull from an iPhone wireframe PSD after some Google'ing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                                                                           target:self 
                                                                           action:@selector(addButtonPressed:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = addButton;
[addButton release], addButton = nil;
```

This will get the framework to add the `+` icon.

Sorry I've read over the WebApp bit, just use an image.

Comment: I'm asking for this: an image or the CSS properties for the plus character. Anyhow +1 for answering :)